# Download an executable .phar file with php and curl

Tags: php, curl, command-line-interface, executable, phar

I'm trying to make a php script that downloads an executable with curl. So far I am able to download the file, but after downloading, the file is not executable (ie if you run `php wp-cli.phar` nothing happens). I realize this is an expected behaviour to prevent security risks, so how do I tell curl that I want the downloaded file to be treated as an executable ? The equivalent command from the command line is : `curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar`

This is my code, which tries to implement the above command in a php script, but the resulting file is not executable:

```
set_time_limit(0);
$fp = fopen ('./wp-cli.phar', 'w+');
$ch = curl_init('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

**EXTRA INFORMATION**
If you would like to reproduce the error, create a file called `a.php` with the contents above. Then run `php a.php` and then run `php wp-cli.phar --info`

Comment: When you say "nothing happens" what do you mean? You get no output from running that command? Check the permissions and owner/group of the file. Is it even executable by the user running `php`? Is the downloaded file in the same relative directory to where you're trying to execute it?

Comment: Creating a file doesn't automatically make it an executable, you need to change permissions ( `chmod 775 filename` on Linux CLI)

Comment: @Andy By "nothing happens" I mean that I get no output, yes, as if I typed a blank command. The permissions of the file are `-rw-r--r--` and I am the owner. Yes, I am running both scripts (the one you see and the one downloaded) from the same directory, both are there.

@NigelRen Still the same. I even tried it with `chmod` function of php before.

Comment: So it has no executable permissions which is why you cannot execute it. Use Nigel Ren's suggestion. You should see an `x` (meaning eXecutable) in the permissions, `r-x`

Comment: Weird, now it's working normally, I can't reproduce the error ... I'll do some more tests on my full code. Thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below, this is currently what we are using to download files from a url.

```
public function  downloadFile($url, $filepath){
     $fp = fopen($filepath, 'w+');
     $ch = curl_init($url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
     curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch);
     fclose($fp);

     return (filesize($filepath) > 0)? true : false;
 }
```

Comment: I just tested your function, thanks for sharing, but still the same behaviour with the file created like this `downloadFile('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar', 'wp-cli.phar');`

Comment: @GeorgeDimitriadis I've answered your original post. It's nothing to do with how you're downloading it. It's to do with the fact you cannot execute it - no executable permissions on the file.